# Rythm is changing my mailId <name>@gmail.com as it contains "@"

Tags: rythm

I am using Rythm to modify multiple strings in my main String Object. Issue is my main String Object contains mail Id also. As I don't want to replace @gmail.com, I have not declared it in the Template. But Rythm is trying to modify that also.
 So if I declare my string as "abc@gmail.com" I am getting the below exception.

---

Exception in thread "main" org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: gmail.com cannot be resolved to a type

Template: 0 PIN_FLD_EMAIL_ID        STR [0] "abc@gmail.com"

### Relevant template source lines:

> > 1: 0 PIN_FLD_EMAIL_ID        STR [0] "abc@gmail.com"

### Relevant Java source lines:

```
@Override public org.rythmengine.utils.TextBuilder build(){
buffer().ensureCapacity(49);
p("0 PIN_FLD_EMAIL_ID STR [0] \"abc"); //line: 1

try{pe(gmail.com);} catch (RuntimeException e)                 {__handleTemplateExecutionException(e);}  //line: 1
p("\""); //line: 1

return this;
}
```

}

---

If I put it like abcgmail.com then it is able to accept it, but I need @ also. Is there is anyway that my String contains "@" and Rythm may keep it as it is ??

Regards
Yogesh Joshi

Answer (score 0):

use two `@@` to escape, so your string should contain `abc@@gmail.com` instead of `abc@gmail.com`. See more on http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#at